# "npm install -g stf" shows error while Stf set up

Tags: android, node.js

> ```
> "I am trying to set up STF(SmartPhone test farm), but while installing NPM and firing command "npm install -g stf" in terminal i
> ```
>
> am getting following errors. "
>
> ```
> Enter code here
>
> sh-3.2# npm install -g stf
> npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.7: use uuid module instead
> /usr/local/bin/stf -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/stf/bin/stf
>
> > dtrace-provider@0.8.0 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/stf/node_modules/bunyan/node_modules/dtrace-provider
> > node scripts/install.js
>
>
> > dtrace-provider@0.7.1 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/stf/node_modules/dtrace-provider
> > node scripts/install.js
>
>
> > bufferutil@1.3.0 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/stf/node_modules/bufferutil
> > node-gyp rebuild
>
> gyp WARN EACCES user "root" does not have permission to access the dev dir "/var/root/.node-gyp/6.9.5"
> gyp WARN EACCES attempting to reinstall using temporary dev dir "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/stf/node_modules/bufferutil/.node-gyp"
> xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command
> ```
>
> line tools instance
>
> ```
> xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command
> ```
>
> line tools instance
>
> ```
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o
>   SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/bufferutil.node
>
> > jpeg-turbo@0.4.0 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/stf/node_modules/jpeg-turbo
> > node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
>
> gyp WARN EACCES user "root" does not have permission to access the dev dir "/var/root/.node-gyp/6.9.5"
> gyp WARN EACCES attempting to reinstall using temporary dev dir "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/stf/node_modules/jpeg-turbo/.node-gyp"
> xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command
> ```
>
> line tools instance
>
> ```
> xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command
> ```
>
> line tools instance
>
> ```
> make: *** No rule to make target `../.node-gyp/6.9.5/include/node/common.gypi', needed by `Makefile'.
> ```
>
> Stop.
>       gyp ERR! build error 
>       gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
>       gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:276:23)
>       gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
>       gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
>       gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:12)
>       gyp ERR! System Darwin 15.3.0
>       gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js"
>   "build" "--fallback-to-build"
>   "--module=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/stf/node_modules/jpeg-turbo/lib/binding/node-v48-darwin-x64/jpegturbo.node"
>   "--module_name=jpegturbo"
>   "--module_path=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/stf/node_modules/jpeg-turbo/lib/binding/node-v48-darwin-x64"
>       gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/stf/node_modules/jpeg-turbo
>       gyp ERR! node -v v6.9.5
>       gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
>       gyp ERR! not ok 
>       node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
>       node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node
>   /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js
>   build --fallback-to-build
>   --module=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/stf/node_modules/jpeg-turbo/lib/binding/node-v48-darwin-x64/jpegturbo.node
>   --module_name=jpegturbo --module_path=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/stf/node_modules/jpeg-turbo/lib/binding/node-v48-darwin-x64'
>   (1)
>       node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/stf/node_modules/jpeg-turbo/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
>       node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
>       node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
>       node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
>       node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
>       node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 15.3.0
>       node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/stf/node_modules/jpeg-turbo/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp"
>   "install" "--fallback-to-build"
>       node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/stf/node_modules/jpeg-turbo
>       node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v6.9.5
>       node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.19
>       node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
>       Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js
>   build --fallback-to-build
>   --module=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/stf/node_modules/jpeg-turbo/lib/binding/node-v48-darwin-x64/jpegturbo.node
>   --module_name=jpegturbo --module_path=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/stf/node_modules/jpeg-turbo/lib/binding/node-v48-darwin-x64'
>   (1)
>       /usr/local/lib
>       └── (empty)
>
> ```
> npm ERR! Darwin 15.3.0
> npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "stf"
> npm ERR! node v6.9.5
> npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> npm ERR! jpeg-turbo@0.4.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
> npm ERR! 
> npm ERR! Failed at the jpeg-turbo@0.4.0 install script 'node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build'.
> npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
> npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the jpeg-turbo package,
> npm ERR! not with npm itself.
> npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
> npm ERR!     node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
> npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
> npm ERR!     npm bugs jpeg-turbo
> npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
> npm ERR!     npm owner ls jpeg-turbo
> npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
> npm ERR!     /Users/indianic/npm-debug.log
> npm ERR! code 1
> ```

Comment: Tiwani   Were you able to resolve this?  We are also running into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

[Help!!! #1961](https://github.com/nodeschool/discussions/issues/1961)

Appears to have had the same issue, hope their fix works for you.